# What is this unused parameter error?

Tags: c, schema, kaa

```
/home/pi/labsdk-RP/client/c/libs/kaa/src/extensions/profile/kaa_profile.c: In function ‘kaa_profile_manager_is_profile_set’:
/home/pi/labsdk-RP/client/c/libs/kaa/src/extensions/profile/kaa_profile.c:195:64: warning: unused parameter ‘self’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 bool kaa_profile_manager_is_profile_set(kaa_profile_manager_t *self)
                                                                ^
/home/pi/labsdk-RP/client/c/libs/kaa/src/extensions/profile/kaa_profile.c: In function ‘kaa_profile_manager_update_profile’:
/home/pi/labsdk-RP/client/c/libs/kaa/src/extensions/profile/kaa_profile.c:394:71: warning: unused parameter ‘self’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 kaa_error_t kaa_profile_manager_update_profile(kaa_profile_manager_t *self, kaa_profile_t *profile_body)
                                                                       ^
/home/pi/labsdk-RP/client/c/libs/kaa/src/extensions/profile/kaa_profile.c:394:92: warning: unused parameter ‘profile_body’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 kaa_error_t kaa_profile_manager_update_profile(kaa_profile_manager_t *self, kaa_profile_t *profile_body)
```

Would like to seek help on what are these errors?
For 195:64

```
bool kaa_profile_manager_is_profile_set(kaa_profile_manager_t *self)
{
#if KAA_PROFILE_SCHEMA_VERSION > 0
    return self->profile_body.buffer != NULL && self->profile_body.size != 0;
#else
    return true;
#endif
}
```

For 394 : 71

```
kaa_error_t kaa_profile_manager_update_profile(kaa_profile_manager_t *self, kaa_profile_t *profile_body)
{
#if KAA_PROFILE_SCHEMA_VERSION > 0
    KAA_RETURN_IF_NIL2(self, profile_body, KAA_ERR_BADPARAM);

    size_t serialized_profile_size = profile_body->get_size(profile_body);
    if (!serialized_profile_size) {
        KAA_LOG_ERROR(self->logger, KAA_ERR_BADDATA,
                      "Failed to update profile: serialize profile size is null. Maybe profile schema is empty");
        return KAA_ERR_BADDATA;
    }
```

For 394 :

```
kaa_error_t kaa_profile_manager_update_profile(kaa_profile_manager_t *self, kaa_profile_t *profile_body)
{
#if KAA_PROFILE_SCHEMA_VERSION > 0
    KAA_RETURN_IF_NIL2(self, profile_body, KAA_ERR_BADPARAM);

    size_t serialized_profile_size = profile_body->get_size(profile_body);
    if (!serialized_profile_size) {
        KAA_LOG_ERROR(self->logger, KAA_ERR_BADDATA,
                      "Failed to update profile: serialize profile size is null. Maybe profile schema is empty");
        return KAA_ERR_BADDATA;
    }
```

Would like to understand more about these errors because these are generated as default and with the demo application , it works perfectly fine...

Comment: Am I correct to assume that `KAA_PROFILE_SCHEMA_VERSION <= 0`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error but a warning.

Let's say you have this code:

```
void Test(int a, int b)
{
  printf ("a = %d\n", a);
}
```

You will get a warning saying that the the `b` parameter is not used, which is obviously the case here.

In your case the `KAA_PROFILE_SCHEMA_VERSION` is certainly defined to somethething smaller than 1:

```
bool kaa_profile_manager_is_profile_set(kaa_profile_manager_t *self)
{
#if KAA_PROFILE_SCHEMA_VERSION > 0
    return self->profile_body.buffer != NULL && self->profile_body.size != 0;
#else
    return true;
#endif
}
```

Therefore the actual compiled code is this (`self` is not used):

```
bool kaa_profile_manager_is_profile_set(kaa_profile_manager_t *self)
{
  return true;
}
```

In your case you probably can safely ignore these warnings.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see that you already posted the correct answer.

Comment: @gmug no problem, this happens all the time when people write answer simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

I think the define `KAA_PROFILE_SCHEMA_VERSION` is not set or set to a value <= 0. That's the reason that the code after the lines `#if KAA_PROFILE_SCHEMA_VERSION > 0` is not compiled but the code after `#else` which doesn't use the parameters of the function declaration. Define `KAA_PROFILE_SCHEMA_VERSION` with a value > 0 and then the errors should disappear.